# twilio call inturuption by receiving sim call ios

Tags: ios, xcode, twilio, voip

We are creating app for iPhone with twilio client to client call . We can achieve that successfully .

The issue is When i create a client to client call and call is in progress i receive another call on sim that inturrupted my twilio call.

Now when I am back to my app the call is disconnected!

How can we stop the call from disconnecting ? cant we reconnect the same call after the PSTN (sim) call hang up ??

Is it possible to put a call on hold while receiving a call ??? and rejoin again !

Please we do need to implement this thing in our app , Kindly guide me !